# Bluetooth speakers do not appear in Sound Settings

Tags: bluetooth, 17.04, bluetooth-speaker

I'm using a computer with Ubuntu 17.04 and an IOGEAR GBU521(W6) bluetooth microadapter installed on it. Consequently I'm having issues attempting to pair it with wireless speakers that I just purchased. It recognizes the speakers and says they're connected but in the 'Sound Settings' they do not appear in the 'Play Sound Through' option and thus will not play.

Furthermore, when I look up GBU521(W6) on the "Product Driver & Firmware" section of IOGEAR's website there are no Linux files listed, so I'm unclear as to how to proceed.

If you can, please help!

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `pactl list short | grep blue`

Answer (score 1):

Steps you can try

- Try to disconnect and connect again
- Check if you are using the correct mode of pairing. Different devices have different methods
- Initiate the connection once from the speaker side and also once from the computer side. Do this multiple times. It has often worked for me after a number of attempts
- Change sound output from mono to stereo and vice versa(basically change the Bluetooth sound profile. A2DP is Stereo). This does the magic many times